# 100% width image, keep ratio with min-height

Tags: css

I want an image to be 100% BUT have a `min-height` of 500px when the image reaches this height I want the ratio to stay (basically) turn off 100% width. I know this is possible with javascript but I've never seen it done with css. Is it possible?

Comment: The question is unclear. Can you include examples of what you expect to happen with images of various sizes.

Comment: Hope I understand this. If you want to image width 100% after 500px height, You can use @mediaquery (min-height: 500px) { img {width: 100%;} }

Comment: They way you have written your question, I understand that you don't need a `min-height`, but instead a `max-height`.

Comment: you need to make your question more clear and include some CSS+HTML.

Comment: I basically want to set the `min-width` without knowing the variable width of the image. I know I want `min-height` to be `500px`. If I set `width:100%;min-height:500px` the ratio get's all out of wack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**html**

```
<img src="/path.jpg" />
```

**CSS**

```
img { min-height: 500px; }
```

**notice**

Just ensure you had not defined width for this image in  element or in css for upper elements. If everything is ok -- image would be scaled to min-height keeping ratio.

And keep in mind to use larger images then your min-height -- otherwise it would be ugly.